# How to use logger configurations, defined in appsettings.json, in ILogger?

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging

I have an application with the following appsettings.json file, containing logging configurations:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Warning"
    },
    "Console": {
      "FormatterName": "Console",
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "SingleLine": true,
        "IncludeScopes": true,
        "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK : ",
        "UseUtcTimestamp": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i create the logger instance in this way (not using IHost, etc.).

```
ILogger logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger<Program>();
```

So my question is how the Ilogger to be made to use the configurations from appsettings.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ILoggerFactory` is designed to be used with dependency injection, you'd usually use `IServiceCollection.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()` rather than `new LoggerFactory()`, and in your host setup you'd hook up the configuration for that `GetService`.

If you can use it that really is better, as the .NET services setup already has the configuration and is pretty well optimised. It has built in console support by default.

As it without that you don't have access to the `GetService` or the `hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")` you'd call to get the config. You have to set this up yourself.

First to get the config:

```cs
// Read the app settings file, you can add secrets and additional files here
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

// Build the configuration
var configuration = builder.Build();

// Load the section for the logger
var loggingConfig = configuration.GetSection("Logging");
```

Now every time you call `new LoggerFactory()` you need to set it up with providers that you want to write to:

```cs
// Create the factory
var factory = new LoggerFactory();

ILoggerProvider yourCustomProvider = // whatever you want to do here, using your loggingConfig 

// Add your custom provider
factory.AddProvider(yourCustomProvider);
```

Then, whenever you call `factory.CreateLogger<...>();` you'll get an `ILogger` that outputs to your provider.